# update session and refresh page with ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I need help with a script that according to 2 parameters updated me a `$ _SESSION` variable and then refresh the page.  One of these parameters comes from a select and the other according to a select class `"active"`.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="simple-drop-down">
<select id="select-order">
    <option>Price</option>
    <option>Category</option>
    <option>A - Z</option>
</select>
```

And my jquery function like this:

```
function order_visual() {

var type_order = $('#loader-wrapper').val();
var arrow_order = $( "#select-arrow" ).hasClass( "active" );

$.ajax({
    url: "visual.php?order="+type_order="&"+arrow_order,
    type: "post",
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
        location.reload();
    }
});


});
```

And then the PHP is a simple script that manages the `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Why are you sending a POST request if you are sending your data as a query string in the URI ? Do you mean to send a GET request?

Comment: I believe he is using post because he then expects to refresh the page, he isnt getting new data to insert into the site, he is rebuilding it on the server  side with php.

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working with this code? I also see another alternative, you could just use queries in your site url and just go to it like that without using ajax or a refresh.

Comment: how does the HTML you are showing pertain to the JS code? In your JS, I see you are using the elements `#loader-wrapper` and `#select-arrow`, but I do not see the HTML for this.

Comment: @Sean_A91 regardless if he is using the retrieved data to refresh or not, if the data he is sending is in the URI, then the request should be GET. If a POST is needed he would need to create an object and send it with AJAX through the `data` option. I guess we would need more information from the user to understand their main goal.